# Recording name conflict when linking

Tags: solaris, ld

When compiling project on Solaris I get ld fatal error:

> fatal: recording name conflict 'path/lib.so' and 'otherpath/lib.so' provide identical dependency.

Libs are the same, but cmake somehow generates makefile linking to both. It does work under Linux, but on Solaris it does not. Is there any flags or any other way to compile it? I use Sun 12.6 compiler.

Comment: Post the link command.